# Wordpress image link not correct

Tags: wordpress

I'm having a problem with my WordPress site. The image URL is not correct.it shows like this

https://example.comwp-content/uploads/2019/12/unesco_sdg.png instead of https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/unesco_sdg.png. There is missing / after domain name

Comment: Please provide more information. Where you get this issue on your site? You should show some piece of code that you have tried and cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this brother

```
echo site_url().'/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/unesco_sdg.png';
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/images/unesco.jpg' ?>
```

First print this and then according to the structure, put yours.